# Bugs after upload Image in Magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, troubleshooting

I have a problem with Magento, because when I try to upload files, images in the Magento admin panel location:

```
1. Catalog -> Manage product -> Images
```

I get the error: "SSL Error: Invalid or Self-signed Certification"

```
2. System-> configuration-> Catalog-> Catalog-> Product Image Placeholder
```

I get the error: "Unable to load the webpage becouse the server sent no data."

The following link is screenschot of these errors.
http://prntscr.com/7hjyig

Probably ubuntu server is misconfigured, but I gave full rights to the folder media and for other directories and it does not help..

I installed correctly in the domain SSL certificate
but still they show up the same bugs.
Please help me get tired of this problem for a few weeks ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `self-signed certificate` (magento uses a flash plugin to upload product images)

See

[(IE) Installing a Self-Signed Certificate as a Trusted Root CA](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2007/04/10/installing-a-self-signed-certificate-as-a-trusted-root-ca-in-windows-vista.aspx)

[How do I configure OS X to use my self-signed SSL certificate?](http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-connect/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/how-do-i-configure-os-x-to-use-my-self-signed-ssl-certificate-268.html)

If you are using your base url as http://localhost

> NOTE:
>
> Magento requires itself to be installed on a host name with at least
>   one period ‘.’ in it, therefore installing to http://localhost doesn’t
>   work. (Having installed to //localhost, I was unable to get it running
>   even after the following changes. In the end I had to reinstall using
>   the new host name which then worked fine.)

**[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837347/ssl-error-invalid-or-self-signed-certificate-magento-image-upload-in-products)**

Comment: Self-signed SSL certificate is installed but still receive the error. Please help.

Comment: What is your url?

Comment: https://mobilaizer.pl , please look - https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=mobilaizer.pl

Comment: I would suggest to make your url with `www`, so it becomes  `http://www.mobilaizer.pl` or `https://www.mobilaizer.pl` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I have certified only on mobilaizer.pl, I have to buy a second ssl certificate under www.mobilaizer.pl, how do you think the problem may be a flash uploader?

Comment: You don't need to, it's same thing. [link](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=http://www.mobilaizer.pl)

Comment: ok, I will do, but as these problems will continue, whether to install an additional: https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader, because it can be a problem with the flash uploader magento?

Comment: With fresh magento, I don't have this problem like yours. Although, I would suggest you to report it to "SSL certifier".